# Bash - Salvar erros em uma variavel

Tags: bash

Estou rodando um script em bash que salva as mensagens de erro em um arquivo .txt de log, preciso salvar as mensagens de erro em uma variável  agora, segue exemplo:

```
LOG="/home/control/log.txt"
exec 2>>$LOG
tar -zcf teste.tar.gz teste
```

Ele zipa a pasta teste e grava os erros no log.txt
Preciso q grave numa variável para imprimir os erros!

Answer (score 2):

talvez

```
LOG="/home/control/log.txt"
tar -zcf teste.tar.gz teste 2>>$LOG
```

Answer (score 1):

`foobar.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR=$(tar -zcf foobar.tar.gz foo.txt bar.txt )
echo "${VAR}"
exit 0
```

Testando:

```
$ ./foobar.sh 
tar: foo.txt: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: bar.txt: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Comment: rodei esse código q me passou mas não imprimiu os erros na variavel, ela ficou vazia!

Comment: @A.S.: Talvez a variável pemaneceu vazia pois o comando `tar` apresenta um comportamento 'silencioso' quando obtém sucesso.

Comment: Se colocar um -v no `tar -zcvf` ele vai imprimir no STDOUT mesmo se o tar executar com sucesso

Answer (score 0):

Por que motivo você "precisa" colocar numa variável ?
Eu acho isso questionável, mas enfim...

Parece que o melhor jeito é seguir esta sugestão de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962255/how-to-store-standard-error-in-a-variable-in-a-bash-script:

Rodar tudo num sub-shell e redirecionar a saída de erros para a saída padrão, que é capturada pela variável ERRORS. No sub-shell, a saída padrão é ignorada (redirecionada para /dev/null). É interessante.

```
ERRORS=$( (tar -zcf teste.tar.gz teste > /dev/null) 2>&1 )
```

**PS 1**: assim como no SO em inglês, não testei a solução...
**PS 2**: no original são usadas chaves {} para rodar o sub-shell, mas acho que o mais comum é usar parênteses mesmo
**PS 3**: no original tem um ';' antes do parêntese interno, assim `...teste ; )`, não sei se precisa mesmo